# How do we set HttpOnly Flag in a Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring-mvc, setcookie, httponly

Is there an annotation for setting the HttpOnly and Secure flag in a spring application?
I know we could do it through web.xml. However, right now only the code is accessible to me and not the web.xml. So is there a way I can do it in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: why can you not edit web.xml?

Comment: The application is a small part of another application under which the web.xml is defined. So changing the web.xml is out of my project scope. However, I still need to resolve the issue of HttpOnly and Secure Flag.